# Найти следующей элемент в Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Допустим есть база данных в firebase. В этой базе есть картинки. Есть андроид приложение на котлин Листалка картинок. Какой запрос сделать к бд чтобы найти следующий элемент в бд. Как найти следующую картинку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть startAfter и limit, в лимит указываете 1, в startAfter позицию и обрабатываете.
Если я ошибаюсь поправьте

Answer (score 0):

Получаете ссылку на БД, выводите данные в RecyclerView. В результате будут все картинки по очереди.

Comment: мне нужно свайпом вправо например получит следующую картинку в бд

Comment: Так, а в чем проблема ? Получить запрос или реализовать свайп ? Есть много разных библиотек для свайпа, к примеру - https://github.com/AndroidCodility/HorizontalRecyclerview .

Comment: дело не в самом свайпе. "Какой запрос сделать к бд чтобы найти следующий элемент в бд" Вот в чем проблема

Comment: Чтобы получить конкретную фотографию - надо сделать конкретный запрос к этой фотографии. Чтобы сделать вывод всех фотографий - надо сделать немного другой запрос и вывод в RecyclerView. В обычный RecyclerView или горизонтальный, я думаю, уже другой вопрос. Это же только визуальное отображение. Горизонтальная прокрутка это ведь тот же самый RecyclerView.

Comment: С библиотекой, которую я кидал выше, я не работал, но там же в описании пишет, что работают с библиотекой CardView + RecyclerView. Тоже самое, что и Вам надо же.

Comment: вы не поняли. Вопрос вообще не про отображение. Вот например в базе 6 картинок 1.2.3.4.5.6 . Зная айди картинки 5 как узнать 4 и 6 ? Какой запрос отправить к Firebase ?

Comment: Извините за опоздание. Вообще, если знать то, что айди 5, можно сделать запрос id-1, или id+1. К примеру, вы получаете картинку по ссылке child("id").getValue().toString. Айди тут 5. И если изменить айди на -1 или +1, то будут нужные вам картинки, если я все правильно понимаю. Я просто не пойму, зачем Вам все это делать, если можно сделать вывод всех картинок через recyclerView, как вам удобно, горизонтально или вертикально.

Comment: если есть программа на подобии айдаприкол в базе которой стотыщпицот картинок неужели лучший вариант выводить все картинки. А на счет айди 5+1 в файр бейсе другие айди. 5c46942c-a873-4c2a-b824-16866e3735ab вот такие сюда если прибавить 1 что получится? видимо тут либо не знают ответ либо те кто знает молчит.

Comment: Firebase дает 2 возможности выводить информацию.  К примеру. 1ый вариант: есть 100 картинок, в результате выводит 100 картинок. 2ой вариант: есть 100 картинок, в результате выводит, к примеру, первые 20, затем, если пользователь прокрутит где-то 15 из 20, идет подгрузка еще 20, затем, если прокрутит, пойдет еще прогрузка остальных и т.п..